# Investigate the convergence of $i^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have to split this into real and imaginary parts and find the limit of the them separately to check convergence. But I have no idea how to separate $i^n$ into real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Why?  You get $i, -1, -i, 1$ repeating in an infinite cycle.

Comment: The question asks for it to be answered by splitting into real and imaginary parts.

Comment: OK, well the real parts go $0, -1, 0, 1$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
i^n
&=(\cos{(\pi/2)}+i\sin{(\pi/2)})^n\\
&=\cos{(n\pi/2)}+i\sin{(n\pi/2)}\\
\end{align}
By applying De Moivre's Theorem in the second line. Note that neither of the real or imaginary parts converge as they are just $\cos{(n\pi/2)}$ and $\sin{(n\pi/2)}$ respectively.

Comment: How would you use that method for (1+i)^n?

Comment: \begin{align}(1+i)^n&=(\sqrt{2}(\cos{(\pi/4)}+i\sin{(\pi/4)}))^n\\&=(\sqrt{2})^n(\cos{(n\pi/4)}+i\sin{(n\pi/4)})\\\end{align}Then neither of $(\sqrt{2})^n\cos{(n\pi/4)}$ or $(\sqrt{2})^n\sin{(n\pi/4)}$ converge.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how to calculate that. I understand where the sqrt(2) comes from but am unsure how to find what goes inside of the cos and sin.

Comment: Its the polar form of the complex number. Any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ can be written as $$z=|z|(\cos{(\arg{(z)})}+i\sin{(\arg{(z)})})$$The principal argument of $1+i$ is $\pi/4$.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since $i^2=-1$, $i^4=(-1)^2=1$, so $i^{n+4}=i^n$. Since $i^n$ has period $4$, its real part has period $4$ with values $1,\,0,\,-1,\,0$ for $n$ from $0$ to $3$ inclusive. Similarly, the imaginary part has period $4$ with seed $0,\,1,\,0,\,-1$. None of these period sequences converge, but they do all satisfy $u_{n+2}=-u_n$ (since $i^{n+2}=-i^n$), which makes the seeds easier to compute.

Answer (score 0):

$$i^0=\ \ \ 1+0i$$
$$i^1=\ \ \ 0+1i$$
$$i^2=-1+0i$$
$$i^3=\ \ \ 0-1i$$
$$i^4=\ \ \ 1+0i$$
$$i^5=\ \ \ 0+1i$$
$$i^6=-1+0i$$
$$\cdots$$